# Eclipse: quick add brackets, quotation marks, etc like in NetBeans

Tags: eclipse

Netbeans has this small feature: I have some text in my editor like `This is a text`. When I select this text, and press the `"` key, the selected text gets surrounded by that character. So I get `"This is a text"`. This works with brackets too, by pressing `[` I get `[This is a text]`... etc... It even replaces the first and the last characters if they are special, so after pressing `"` on `'Text'` it becames `"Text"`...

anyway... is there any similar functionality in eclipse?

Comment: How did you manage to get that feature in NetBeans? This doesn't work for me with Nb 7.0. Would be a nice-to-have

Answer (score 1):

I think not. 
With Eclipse you can do the inverse. Click on " and write the text, you will get "text"

Answer (score 1):

Could be a nice addition to Eclipse! Please open a bug against Eclipse JDT/UI https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=JDT